# Set initial value of a tf.Variable Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have this function:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))
```

And I call it like this, for example:

```
# shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_filters, num_input_channels]
shape = [1, 1, 8, 1]

weights = new_weights(shape)
```

I want to initialize my weights with the following values:

```
weights = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And after initializing it with these values, I want it to be updated (trainable).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use assign function

```
shape = [1, 1, 8, 1]

weights = new_weights(shape)

ws = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

ws = np.array(ws).reshape(shape)
weights = weights.assign(ws)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use function like this:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    total = np.prod(shape)
    init_data = np.array(range(1, 1+ total)).reshape(shape)
    return tf.get_variable(name='weights', 
                           initializer = tf.constant_initializer(init_data), 
                           shape = shape)
```

and check it:

```
shape = [1, 1, 8, 1]
weights = new_weights(shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `tf.Variable(initial_value=weights, ...)` ?